# Unable to delete data from dynamically assigned table at PostgreSQL13

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, postgresql-13

**Unable to delete from dynamically assigned table data at PostgreSQL13.**

***Basically I want to archive 10 days older PostgreSQL data to another table. I want to pass days, source table and target table as a argument to this stored procedure but unable to do it due to formatting issue in WITH statement. I found syntax error with FORMAT. Is here anyone can help me out on this?***

```
create or replace procedure data_archiver(
    retain_days integer,
    prod_main_table varchar(100),  
    archive_table_name varchar(100), 
    my_schema_name varchar(100)
)
language plpgsql
as $$
    declare _data_count integer;
    declare _date_time timestamp;
    declare _prod_main_tbl varchar:=prod_main_table;
    declare _archive_table_name varchar:=archive_table_name;
begin
    _date_time=TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(now()- interval  '1 days' * retain_days, 'yyyy-mm-dd'),'YYYY-MM-DD');
    _data_count=(SELECT count(*) FROM  FORMAT('%I',prod_main_table) WHERE updated_at<_date_time);

IF EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables WHERE  schemaname = 'public' AND tablename  = FORMAT('%I',prod_main_table)) 
   THEN
            RAISE NOTICE 'Table public.archive_table_name already exists.';
            WITH purge_table as (DELETE FROM FORMAT('%I',prod_main_table)  WHERE updated_at<_date_time RETURNING  *) 
            INSERT INTO FORMAT('%I',archive_table_name) select * from purge_table;
            RAISE NOTICE 'Table public.archive_table_name already exists.Total data archived: %',_data_count;
   ELSE
            RAISE NOTICE 'Table public.archive_table_name NOT exists. Table created';
            CREATE TABLE FORMAT('%I',archive_table_name)  as TABLE FORMAT('%I',prod_main_table) WITH NO DATA; 
            WITH purge_table as (DELETE FROM FORMAT('%I',prod_main_table)  WHERE updated_at<_date_time RETURNING  *) 
            INSERT INTO FORMAT('%I',archive_table_name) select * from purge_table;  
            RAISE NOTICE 'Table public.archive_table_name table created.Total data archived: %',_data_count;
   END IF;
end; $$
```

Found below syntax error at PostgreSQL 13.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 26:      WITH purge_table as (DELETE FROM FORMAT('%I',prod_main_...
                                                     ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 1042
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot dynamically construct a table name in a static SQL statement. You would need to use dynamic SQL and `EXECUTE`. Have you considered partitioning as a simple solution to your problem?

Comment: How can I execute dynamic SQL and EXECUTE, I am little confused. Can you share a example?

Comment: It is all very clearly documented in the PostgreSQL documentation.